# how i can visible textarea box using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, captcha

I'm making automation script in python using selenium so i want to visible textarea box because i want to put it into some arguments and i'm using this code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('g-recaptcha-response')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = '';", element)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.margin = '100px 200px';", element)
```

but above code is not working for me as you can see here:

[image]

Could you please tell me how I can show textarea box? [Link to the page](https://m.jeuxvideo.com/login?url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.jeuxvideo.com%2Fforums%2F0-4501-0-1-0-1-0-star-ixiom.htm&hash=a8e309f2189375923740ff14baa289c5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arguments[0].style.display = 'block';
arguments[0].parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
```

The problem is that setting style.display to an empty string is interpreted as setting the display to "none" and that makes the element invisible. The textarea also sits in a parent which sits in a parent with the styling "display: none" so to solve that just go to the parent of the parent and set its display to "block".

Comment: i sent arguments into textarea box but i don't how to submit it? could you please help me out here?

Comment: It seems to be working for me... could you describe the problem in greater detail?